# Cloudkit attribute won't show up in fetch request after updating record attribute

Tags: swift, dictionary, nsdata, cloudkit

I want to save a dictionary object to CloudKit so I archived the dictionary as an NSData object and saved it to a Bytes attribute named "stats" in my record. When I save the record and call println(), the record returns all the attributes I wanted including the NSData object. However when I go and fetch that record with its recordID, the NSData object isn't there. Not sure whats happening.

Here is the code for my save function:

```
let recordIDData = entity.valueForKey("recordID") as! NSData
        let recordID = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(recordIDData) as! CKRecordID
        let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(statDictionary)

        publicDB.fetchRecordWithID(recordID, completionHandler: {(record, error) -> Void in
            if(error != nil){
                self.notifyUser("Save Error", message: "The Record Wasn't Saved")
            }else{
                record.setObject(data, forKey: "stats")
                println(record)
            }
        })
```

Here is the code from my view controller which fetches the record

```
let data = record!.objectForKey("stats") as? NSData
    if(data != nil){
        let stats = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data!) as! NSDictionary
        notifyUser("Success!", message: "The Dictionary was retrieved!")

        println(stats)
    }
    println(record!)
    let opponent = record!.objectForKey("opponent") as! String
```

It is important to note that the objectForKey("opponent") call returns the correct string from the record.

Also, I know that the statsDictionary object has values because I also save this dictionary to coreData simultaneously and it works fine when I retrieve the data that way. Even in CloudKit Dashboard the record doesn't show anything saved in the stats attribute.

Here is the console log for when I save:

```
statsDictionary = [section1Digs: 1, section1Assists: 1, section1Hits: 7, section1Blocks: 4, section1Points: 1]

<NSManagedObject: 0x1700af060> (entity: GirlsVolleyball; id: 0xd000000000300002 <x-coredata://21F5B76F-ECDB-400A-8BEB-06D201EC6C1C/GirlsVolleyball/p12> ; data: {
date = "05/10, 03:55 PM";
location = Home;
opponent = Haverhill;
recordID = <62706c69 73743030 d4010203 0405062d 2e582476 65727369 6f6e5824 6f626a65 63747359 24617263 68697665 72542474 6f70>;
stats = <62706c69 73743030 d4010203 0405062a 2b582476 65727369 6f6e5824 6f626a65 63747359 24617263 68697665 72542474 6f70>;
timeStamp = nil;})

<CKRecord: 0x170130680; recordType=Volleyball, recordID=326024E8-A25C-46A7-9C21-AE988D1CBA54:(_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__), recordChangeTag=i9svtxn2, values={
date = "05/10, 03:55 PM";
gender = girls;
location = Home;
opponent = Haverhill;
publishData = No;
stats = <62706c69 73743030 d4010203 0405062a 2b582476 65727369 6f6e5824 6f626a65 63747359 24617263 68697665 72542474 6f701200 0186a0ad 0708191a 1b1c1d1e 1f202122 2355246e 756c6cd3 090a0b0c 1218574e 532e6b65 79735a4e 532e6f62 6a656374 73562463 6c617373 a50d0e0f 10118002 80038004 80058006 a5131415 16178007 80088009 800a800b 800c5c73 65637469 6f6e3144 6967735f 100f7365 6374696f 6e314173 73697374 735c7365 6374696f 6e314869 74735e73 65637469 6f6e3142 6c6f636b 735e7365 6374696f 6e31506f 696e7473 233ff000 00000000 00233ff0 00000000 00002340 1c000000 00000023 40100000 00000000 233ff000 00000000 00d22425 26275a24 636c6173 736e616d 65582463 6c617373 65735c4e 53446963 74696f6e 617279a2 28295c4e 53446963 74696f6e 61727958 4e534f62 6a656374 5f100f4e 534b6579 65644172 63686976 6572d12c 2d54726f 6f748001 00080011 001a0023 002d0032 00370045 004b0052 005a0065 006c0072 00740076 0078007a 007c0082 00840086 0088008a 008c008e 009b00ad 00ba00c9 00d800e1 00ea00f3 00fc0105 010a0115 011e012b 012e013b 01440156 0159015e 00000000 00000201 00000000 0000002e 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000160>;}>
```

The only strange thing is that the NSData value appears to be different on the record than on the CoreData entity.

Here is the console log for when I retrieve that same record moments later:

```
<CKRecord: 0x17012cb20; recordType=Volleyball, recordID=326024E8-A25C-46A7-9C21-AE988D1CBA54:(_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__), recordChangeTag=i9svtxn2, values={
date = "05/10, 03:55 PM";
gender = girls;
location = Home;
opponent = Haverhill;
publishData = No;}>
```

Not sure why the stats attribute doesn't show up.

Anyways... HELP

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

I was simply retrieving the record but I wasn't saving it back into the cloud so I just called a saveRecord function within the completion block for the fetchRecordWithID function and it worked!